# How to concatenate last non-blank cells values from multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I like to know how to get last non-blank cells values from multiple columns in neat way, i.e. the expectd value highlighted in green

[image]

I know how to get last non-blank cell in a column by applying

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW())<>""),INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW())),"")`

and then join multi columns by applying

`=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,G4:L4)`

I have thought several possible ways, such as:

1. transform the source data from 2D array to 1D array and return as array formula;
2. use array if;
3. loop by row instead of columns.

But I cannot think of any neat formula and work properly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one row, you can:

1. filter for non-blank cells
2. take the right-most column

   =LET(r,A4:F4,TAKE(FILTER(r,r<>""),-1))

[image]

To do this in a single spilled formula, just put that calculation into BYROW:

```
=LET(d,A4:F16,BYROW(d,LAMBDA(r,TAKE(FILTER(r,r<>""),-1))))
```

[image]

Edit: to apply the textjoin, you can use this:

```
=LET(
    d, A4:F16,
    BYROW(
        d,
        LAMBDA(r,
            LET(
                lastletter, TAKE(FILTER(r, r <> ""), -1),
                position, XMATCH(lastletter, r),
                seqend, CODE(INDEX(lastletter, 1, 1)),
                seqstart, INDEX(seqend - position + 1, 1, 1),
                seq, SEQUENCE(seqend - seqstart + 1, , seqstart),
                TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, CHAR(seq))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I cannot think of how to develop your formula with conjunction. e.g Cell G5 in your first picture returns value as AB, rather than B.

Comment: @8平民 please see the edit to my answer for a solution. If the answer helps, please upvote and accept the answer as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote. And sadly I cannot use Byrow and Take in my excel version. I believe it should work and am working on work around myself. Therefore, I accepted your reply as solution. Thanks again.

Comment: If you can't use BYROW, then just have one formula per row. Instead of TAKE, you can use `LET(f,FILTER(r,r<>""),INDEX(f,1,COLUMNS(f))`

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering if there is a way to modify your answer to work with words situations as well. Currently, your answer work with characters situations.

Comment: Perhaps open a new question for that, because I think it will be a different approach

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. New post opened for any ideas again. https://superuser.com/questions/1758118/how-to-concatenate-multiple-last-non-blank-cells-values-from-contiguous-columns