# How to concatenate multiple last non-blank cells values from contiguous columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I like to know use excel formula how to join multiple last non-blank cells values from contiguous columns in neat way, i.e. my expected values are highlighted in green in the illustrations.
[image: Illustration]

[image]

I know how to get last non-blank cell values from one column by applying

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW())<>""),INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW())),"")`

I also known how to join multi values by applying

`=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,G4:L4)`

Possible ways I could think of are:

1. transform the source data from 2D array to 1D array and return as array formula;
   My idea is like by applying a formula then can fill up those blank cell values by last non blank cell.

> Source formula ={1,0,0;0,2,0;0,0,3;4,0,0;0,5,0;0,0,6}
> Array return after applying formula ={1,0,0;1,2,0;1,2,3;4,0,0;4,5,0;4,5,6}

2. use array if;
3. loop by row instead of columns.

But I fail to develop proper formula.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

The solution for characters are stated in the link
[Solution on character case](https://superuser.com/questions/1758079/how-to-concatenate-last-non-blank-cells-values-from-multiple-columns)

Comment: You asked a similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1758079/how-to-concatenate-last-non-blank-cells-values-from-multiple-columns) today! Why haven't you tried the use/modify the formula given to you on that question?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio it was my suggestion to post a new question. I think the solution is probably quite different. If that was a mistake, then it's my fault.

Comment: @FlexYourData I understand the suggestion to post a new question. However, the OP doesn't link this question to the previous, nor does he/she state here (in this question) that he/she is looking for a new approach. If you read the two questions without reading the comments, you won't know that a new approach is required as the OP's excel version doesn't have new functions. It is preferable that the OP edits this question and mentions/links to his/her previous one.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I added my previous one link. And elaborate more on my possible way 1.  Hope I get you correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is as you show, with only a single entry in each of the four columns of a row, then:

```
E1: =A1
E2: =TEXTJOIN("",,IF(A2="", E1,""),A2:D2)
```

and fill down

[image]

***Edit** Given your updated example of input and output:*
This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

The basic algorithm consists of filling the rows across; the columns down, and then return a list of the distinct entries from each row.

**M Code**

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source (table name)
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table14"]}[Content],

//set the data types to text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),

//Fill across all rows, then down all columns
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Changed Type"),
    fillRows = Table.FillDown(#"Transposed Table", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transposed Table")),

    #"Transposed Table1" = Table.Transpose(fillRows),
    fillCols = Table.FillDown(#"Transposed Table1", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transposed Table1")),

//Results column combines the Distinct entries only in each of the four columns
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(fillCols, "Output", 
        each Text.Combine(List.Distinct({[Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4]}),""), type text),

//Remove uneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: There are multiple entries in row and column. I added illustration pictures in order to demonstrate the actual structure of the source of data. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @8平民 OK, I see now what you are doing. You still have only a single entry per column in each row, but you might have multiple entries in a given column for a given "group"

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation and I just tested it works. However, as I mentioned in first paragraph in the question, can it be done by applying excel formula in the sake of simplicity and auto update. Thank you again your explanation is very good and detailed.

Comment: @8平民 I don't know how without using functions that, in your related post, you mentioned you did not have in your version of Excel. If you want to use formulas, I suggest you create a bunch of helper columns that effectively fill in the blanks for each column, then `CONCAT` the results.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I will develop bunch of help formula if no further response.